# What does this error mean? "error069040_01.xml"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

We have a shared workbook with Pivot tables and many complex Formulas.  There are five primary users accessing the file daily.  upon opening the file on Sunday after a busy previous week, the file opened with a warning, asked if we wanted to open it with a fix then delivered an error "error069040_01.xml". We were able to Restore the last version from Friday.  There were no issues.  What is the cause of this?

Comment: usually the xml file contains the error log; it is not an error message itself.

Comment: Helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1264639/how-to-fix-error069040-01-xml-in-excel